# TDE Enabled database connection string in ADO.Net using C#

Tags: sql-server, c#-4.0, ado.net, connection-string, tde

I have a .mdf file and i can attach it at run time and access it from C#.But if the same file is TDE enabled i am not getting the format of connection string to be used for attaching it.Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A TDE database cannot be attached from the connections string. It has to be permanently attached to a an Enterprise Edition server and the [decryption certificate must be properly set](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff773063.aspx).

Comment: I am using TDE Enabled mdf file and SqlLocalDb.I need connection string format to use mdf file using C# or else is there any alternative to secure mdf file preventing from attaching and restoring.

Comment: the answer is the same as above.